# Flask Login Manager

Tags: flask, flask-login

I want to build unique/different login pages using login manager because my admin and employee credentials are different from one another. i tried with blueprints, but it showed the same login page for the employee and the administrator.

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
bcrypt = Bcrypt()
user_login_manager = LoginManager()
user_login_manager.login_view = 'admins.login'
user_login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'
emp_login_manager = LoginManager()
emp_login_manager.login_view = 'employees.emp'
emp_login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'

mail = Mail()

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Config)
    db.init_app(app)
    bcrypt.init_app(app)
    mail.init_app(app)
    from project.main.routes import main
    from project.admin.routes import admins
    from project.employee.routes import employees
    from project.manager.routes import managers
    
    user_login_manager.init_app(app)
    user_login_manager.login_view = 'admins.login'
    emp_login_manager.init_app(app)
    emp_login_manager.login_view = 'employees.emp'

    app.register_blueprint(main)
    app.register_blueprint(admins)
    app.register_blueprint(employees)
    app.register_blueprint(managers)
   
    return app

@user_login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(id)

@emp_login_manager.user_loader
def load_emp(employeeid):
    return Employee.query.get(employeeid)

class User(db.Model,UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True,nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60),nullable=False)

class Employee(db.Model,UserMixin):
    employeeid = db.Column(db.String(10),primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(20),nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20),unique=True,nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(60),unique=True,nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.String(5),nullable=False)
    man_name = db.Column(db.String(30),nullable=False)
    managerid = db.Column(db.String(10), nullable=False)

@admins.route("/admin")
@login_required
def admin():
    return render_template('admin.html')

# Create Employee details
@admins.route("/register", methods=["GET","POST"])
def register():
    # creating a registration form passing as an instance

    form = RegistrationForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User( name = form.name.data, email = form.email.data, password = hashed_password)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash(f"Your Account created has been created !",'success')
        return redirect(url_for('admins.login'))
    
    return render_template('register.html',title='Create Account',form=form)

@admins.route("/login", methods=["GET","POST"])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('admins.admin'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email = form.email.data).first()
        if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(user,remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('admins.admin'))
        else:
            flash("Login unsucessful. Please check your email or password!!!")
    
    return render_template('login.html', title='Login', form=form)

@employees.route("/employee", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def employee():
    form = ExpenseForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # Process the form data
        expense = Expense()
        expense.empid = current_user.employeeid
        expense.date = form.date.data
        expense.amount = form.amount.data
        expense.picture = form.picture.data.read()
        expense.managerid = current_user.managerid
        expense.status = 'pending'
        db.session.add(expense)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Expense has been updated successfully!', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('employees.employee'))
    return render_template('employee.html', form=form,user=current_user)

@employees.route("/emp",methods=["GET","POST"])
def emp():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('employees.employee'))
    form = EmpLoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        employee = Employee.query.filter_by(employeeid=form.employeeid.data).first()
        if employee and bcrypt.check_password_hash(employee.password, form.password.data):
            login_user(employee, remember=form.remember.data)
            next_page = request.args.get('next')
            return redirect(next_page) if next_page else redirect(url_for('employees.employee'))
        else:
            flash('Login Unsuccessful. Please check Employee id and password', 'danger')
    return render_template('emp.html', form=form)
```

The admin database differs. Employee databases differ from one another and are not connected. Even if I tried without login manager, the error message "User is not authenticated" appears.